# convert np.where array to list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I try to get indices of an array using `np.where` and wish to concatenate the lists in such a manner that it gives me a 1D list. Is it possible?

```
l = np.array([10,20,14,10,23,5,10,1,2,3,10,5,6,5,10])
y= np.where(l==10)
p=np.where(l==5)
```

If I print y and p, they give me

```
(array([ 0,  3,  6, 10, 14]),)

(array([ 5, 11, 13]),)
```

Upon appending it results in a list of tuples. However the output I want is this:

```
[0,3,6,10,14,5,11,13]
```

Comment: `where` produces a tuple of arrays, one per dimension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since there are many other solutions, I'll show you another way.

You can use `np.isin` to test for good values in your array:

```
goodvalues = {5, 10}
np.where(np.isin(l, goodvalues))[0].tolist() #  [0, 3, 6, 10, 14, 5, 11, 13]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could [concatinate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) both arrays and then convert the result to a list:

```
result = np.concatenate((y[0], p[0])).tolist()
```

Comment: it converts the values to float. How do I keep them int?

Comment: @SunAns why you do think so? Just try `type(np.concatenate((y[0], p[0])).tolist()[0])` and you'll see it's an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the lists with `y[0]` and `p[0]`, then append the results. Just add the line:

```
r = np.append(y[0], p[0])
```

and `r` will be a np.array with the values you asked. Use `list(r)` if you want it as a list.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this with `concatenate`:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([10,20,14,10,23,5,10,1,2,3,10,5,6,5,10])
y = np.where(l==10)[0]
p = np.where(l==5)[0]
k = np.concatenate((y, p))

print(k) # [ 0  3  6 10 14  5 11 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

An other addition to the existing ones in one line.

```
l = np.array([10,20,14,10,23,5,10,1,2,3,10,5,6,5,10])

y = np.where((l == 10) | (l == 5))[0]
```

Numpy works with operators such as `&` (and), `|` (or), and `~` (not). The `where` function returns a tuple in case you pass a boolean array and hence the index 0.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
y = [items for items in y[0]]
p = [items for items in p[0]]
```

then

```
new_list = y + p
```